# Excel, want to read a column and sum up the values that match in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the table below and i want it to read through columns A-B and then sum the values that match their names in columns C-D.

So that in a column elsewhere of a list of names i have the sum of their values from this table. For example Ed features in both columns with a value of 1 and 3, so would return a value of 4. Struggling to get this to work nicely. My actual table consists of 4 columns names and two sets of 4 columns with numbers.

[image: Screenshot]

```
A       B       C   D
Steve   Jeff    4   1
James   Calum   1   1
Alex    Andy    2   1
Peter   Ed      0   3
Owen    Harry   1   2
Jeff    Steve   4   1
James   Calum   1   1
Andy    Alex    2   1
Peter   Owen    0   3
Ed      Harry   1   2
```

Comment: @davidmneedham: Good job on fixing the formatting, but, having done that, there was no reason to insert a screenshot also. We prefer not to have unnecessary images in questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I prefer the screenshots, but the text is helpful for copy/paste. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: Sorry for the format issue, will try to resolve when i put my next query in. Thanks

Comment: FYI, the more-or-less authoritative post on the subject is [Please don’t post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408) on our sister site, [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). While most of the points argue why you *should* have text (which you seem to already understand), #3 gives a reason why you shouldn’t have an image *in addition to* text. (On the other hand, see [Show your Excel results](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11990/150988).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF`, e.g.

`=SUMIF(A:B,"ed",C:D)`

replace "ed" with a cell value which contains your name, e.g.

With names in `F2` down use this in `G2`

`=SUMIF(A:B,F2,C:D)`

`SUMIF` works on a 1 to 1 basis so this only sums column C when column A matches and sums column D when B matches

You can also use where ranges are 4 columns wide

Comment: I didn't know that about SUMIF().  Thanks! +1

Comment: Thanks for the help, i hadnt realised it would work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says

> My actual table consists of 4 columns names and two sets of 4 columns with numbers.

I understand that to mean that you have 12 columns, like this:

```
  A         B         C         D        E     F     G     H      I     J     K     L
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
ALFRED    name      name      name      42     0     0     0     83     0     0     0
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
name      name      BLYTHE    name       0     0     0     0      0     0    60     0
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
name      name      name      BLYTHE     0     0     0    95      0     0     0     0
name      BLYTHE    name      name       0    17     0     0      0     0     0     0
name      name      name      name       0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
```

and you want to get 125 (42+83) for ALFRED and 172 (17+95+60) for BLYTHE. 
In case it’s not obvious from [barry houdini’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1290055/150988#1290060),
you would do that with

```
=SUMIF(A:D, "ALFRED", E:H) + SUMIF(A:D, "ALFRED", I:L)
```

and

```
=SUMIF(A:D, "BLYTHE", E:H) + SUMIF(A:D, "BLYTHE", I:L)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, didn't notice the part about 2 sets of numbers......

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes the table is similar to the one above. Thanks.